# Write a program to get N number of positive non-zero integers, so that the sum and product of these numbers are equal

Tags: php, integer

Let's say, the numbers are `A, B, C, D and E`.

So, what I want is-

```
A + B + C + D + E = A * B * C * D * E
```

I want to write a program (preferably PHP) that solves it.

**Note:** The numbers can be repeated. I mean, we can have `A, B, B, D and E` for example.

Comment: Is it even mathematically possible? Can you give one example?

Comment: Yes. For example, 2 and 2.

Comment: For more than two numbers!

Comment: Never mind. I got it.

Comment: I have solved it myself. Thanks. See the answer below :)

Comment: @NijrajGelani, sure, take any number of zeroes for example...

Comment: @LajosArpad Well, yes of course. But I was thinking something more reasonable. Like this http://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~anow/ps-dvi/si-krl-a.pdf

Comment: @NijrajGelani, then take any number of integers, including 0 in such a way that their sum is 0 (for instance you can include negatives, such a conbination would be -7, -3, 0, 2, 3, 5, for example)

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes! I get it Lajos. Thank you!

Comment: Alright, then I should update my question :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I solved it myself.

The answer is **number of numbers**, **2** and **(number of numbers - 2) of 1s**!

Say, if we consider 5 numbers, they'll be 5, 2, 1, 1 and 1.

If we consider 6 numbers, they'll be 6, 2, 1, 1, 1 and 1.

Here is php program-

```
<?php

$n = 5;

$numbers = array();
$numbers[] = $n;
$numbers[] = 2;
for($i=1; $i<=($n-2); $i++){
    $numbers[] = 1;
}
```

`$numbers` array will contain the numbers!

Comment: You can do that with zeroes as well. Or you can combine with negatives, for instance -5, 0, 5. Or you can do it as you did in your answer, but with 3, 4, etc. For instance: number of numbers, 5 and number of numbers - 2 of 1s. So, your generator idea is a particular solution.